# Simple REST service with WCF

Tags: asp.net, rest

I'm trying to make a simple REST service in VS2010 (.NET 4) with one method that receives three string parameters. I want it to be accessed using both GET and POST (because 3'rd param could be quite big sometimes)

In class MyREST.cs I have this code

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "s={s}&sp={sp}&p={p}")]
    public string Process(string s, string sp, string p)
    {
        // some processing
        return result;
    }
```

Same for POST

When I try to access the service with an url like

```
http://localhost:57129/OneTestREST/s=str1&sp=str2&p=str3
```

I get error

> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: A potentially dangerous
>   Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).

If I change the attribute to

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{s}/{sp}/{p}")]
```

It works ok. But I would like to access it with first syntax

Any idea why is this happening?

Thank you

Comment: From [this site](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/mswinswdev/ms_vbnet_server_error_potentially_dangerous.htm) [i]nstead of turning validation off on a page by page basis you can turn request validation off globally (but in which case be sure to implement item two below). To globally turn request validation off add the following to your web.config file:

<pages validateRequest="false" />

this should go within the <system.web> section. This will turn off request validation for every page in your application. 

Be careful about this though. The warning is there for a reason.

Comment: Thanks, I found that site, but I didn't wanted to use that approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
[WebGet]
public string Process(string s, string sp, string p)
{
    // some processing
    return result;
}
```

then

```
http://localhost:57129/OneTestREST/?s=str1&sp=str2&p=str3
```

Comment: I tried, but it does nothing... it just redirect me to default service page which sais "Endpoint not found. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service."

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the [WebGet] attribute

Comment: I have already that attribute (as you can see in my post) with UriTemplate param. Should I use it without param and just rely on method parameters?